# How to Debug openjdk using gdb?

Tags: gdb, java

I have built openJDK the debugging version with the following configuration options in [README-builds](http://file:///tmp/README-builds-2.html)

```
 bash ./configure ---with-debug-level=slowdebug --with-target-bits=64
```

However I cannot set any breakpoints or to be correct there are no symbols, doing some reseach on google I have found out that I should extract `.diz` (`libjvm.diz`) files in `lib` folder, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: diz stands for debugging information zip. Should be unzipped to be able to load debugging symbols with gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer this for other people, after you get the sources
Follow the steps:

1. `bash ./configure --with-debug-level=slowdebug --with-target-bits=64 --disable-zip-debug-info`
2. `make all`

An information worth mentioning that finally when you start the debugging session with gdb and you run the program you may see a SEGFAULT ignore it and continue till gdb stops at your breakpoint.